# tastypie ignore case on filtering

Tags: django, tastypie

I have added some filters on my Resource

```
filtering = {
    "user" : ALL_WITH_RELATIONS, # to access FK filters
    "state": ALL,
    "job_type": ALL,
}
```

calling is as `http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/?state=Alaska`

Can I modify it so that the filters can ignore case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/?state__iexact=Alaska
```

Default lookup method is `exact`. `iexact` is a case-insensitive exact.

Filtering in Tastypie looks like filtering in Django ORM. Every [field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups) works.

Comment: Thanks, That was what i was looking for. Can you tell me where you got the information from. I cant find it on the tastypie docs

Answer (score 0):

transform your filters into `lowercase`

```
your_filter.lower()
```

But, It only gonna work if you stored your values as lowercase in your DB.

Comment: But that would still not ignore the case. Are you saying that I need to convert both my filters and the DB entries to a single case?

Comment: @WilletteLynch If you get Alaska or AlAskA, you want to parse it as alaska, right ? It's depends on how you stored it in your DB first.

Comment: Yes that is what I need to do. I am using Postgres as my DB, So you are saying that tastypie does not have built in support for ingore case searches ?

Comment: @WilletteLynch tastypie just will parse de data and give to you in order to store it, the key here, is how you store your data and that is your choice.